# Revit Type Library formula comparison against family type

Tags: revit

If I have a property in a Revit Family Type Library that is a Family Type is there a way I can reference the type that is selected in the property for use in formulas.

Say for example I have a parameter "Bolt Washer  (default)" parameter name and the value I have set in the Value field is "Washer : 50x50x3".

I would like to be able to have a value of a another parameter in the type that is changed based on the selected value in the Value field of the Bolt Washer parameter.

For example:

```
IF (Bolt Washer = "50x50x3", 3, IF(Bolt Washer = "65x65x6", 6, 10))
```

[image: Example of family property editor dialogue for the type]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do what you'd like.  Also, you can't reference text of a parameter either.  For example you can't use a formula of: IF(Bolt Text='text',0,1)

You're best best is to make the Bolt Washer Thickness and Bolt Washer Type parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I need them as instance parameters as the washer type can be different depending on the application of the same bolt type.

Answer (score 1):

A revit trick I use to get this functionality, is add a integer parameter to a Revit Family named typeIndex and give each type a unique ID and use this with nested if statements to change properties.

Something like this.

```
if(typeIndex = 1, 100 mm, if(typeIndex = 2, 200 mm, 300 mm))
```